# Comparing two document libraries and copying via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, migration

a customer has two sharepoint online libraries on different sites and wants to migrate one into another. Using "copy to" would be no option for them, they would like to do it via a script.

They have already copied some files to the new site but not all. Therefore they would need a script to compare last edit dates on all files in the libraries and copy them if the edit dates of the files in the old library are more recent. If not, they should not be copied of course.

Is this a possible scenario in PowerShell? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

"copy to" could be an option as this functionality could be implemented via Powershell. Please take a reference of below script:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Admin User Principal Name
$username = 'abc@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'

#Get Password as secure String
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force

#Authenticate
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username , $password)
  
#Function to Move a File
Function Move-SPOFile([String]$SiteURL, [String]$SourceFileURL, [String]$TargetFileURL)
{
    Try{
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $credentials
      
        #sharepoint online powershell to move files
        $CopyMigrationOptions = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CopyMigrationOptions -Property @{"IgnoreVersionHistory"=$false;"IsMoveMode"=$false;"AllowSchemaMismatch"=$true} 
       
        $result = $Ctx.Site.CreateCopyJobs($SourceFileURL,$TargetFileURL,$CopyMigrationOptions)
        
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  
        Write-host -f Green "File Moved Successfully!"
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Moving the File!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
  
#Set Config Parameters
$SiteURL="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/s01"
$SourceFileURL=@("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/s01/Mytestlib/folder01/testfile.chm")
$TargetFileURL="https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/s02/Shared Documents"
  
#Call the function to Move the File
Move-SPOFile $SiteURL $SourceFileURL $TargetFileURL
```

When you click 'copy to' on the UI, the behind request is:

```
..../_api/site/CreateCopyJobs
```

By digging above request, we contructe above cmdlets with CSOM. Below is the info about "CopyMigrationOptions":

```
<ComplexType Name="CopyMigrationOptions">
    <Property Name="AllowSchemaMismatch" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="AllowSmallerVersionLimitOnDestination" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="IgnoreVersionHistory" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="IsMoveMode" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="NameConflictBehavior" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
</ComplexType>
```

As for getting item edit dates, you can achieve it throguh [CSOM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/list-item-operations-using-csom-with-powershell-for-sharepoi/) or [PnP powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps#examples):

```
$item=Get-PnPListItem -List "Documents"
$item["Modified"]
```